# How to get errors in Python subprocess created by java

Tags: java, java-process-runtime

I start the python process by java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python pythonCode.py")` method,

I want to get to know about are there are any errors in python programm and what are those,can i do that?

Comment: There are a boundless number of errors that could come from a python program. If its well written, a non-zero exit code is the basic indicator and other information may be on stderr, stdout or log files. Its like any other program, nothing special about python.

Comment: can I get stderr file to the java programm and inteprete its meaning? I tried ' c=sys.stderr          s="%s"%c.errors
    print("%s"%c.errors)' in python code and I got 98 when I read by java code how to interprete it?

Comment: I'm not a java guy. Since this isn't really a python program it may be best to remove python and subprocess tags. Let the java folks focus on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following suggestion

- Try to write some logs like success.log or failure.log in your python process
  and after Runtime is ran check if success or failure log is there.
- If the process is failed parse the failure log to get the root cause.

hope this will help your question